# html onClick open url stored in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Following is my code, am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`, but i don't see any `}` in my code. `window.open` is expecting url in quotes, I tried different combinations of single and double quotes but not working and unable to escape the double quote in echo either.Please help

Thanks..

```
<?php
$a = "https://www.google.co.in/";

?>

<html>
<body>
<form>

<input type="button" width="100" onClick="window.open(<?php echo '"'; echo $a; echo '"'; ?>)" height="100%" value="Edit Record"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To determine where the problem is, look at your JavaScript and HTML, not at your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting `"` characters into your `onClick` attribute value. Since you use those characters to delimit the value, the first one ends the script in the middle of the statement.

Use `&quot;` instead.

---

But that's a quick and dirty hack. There are better approaches.

- Do not try to generate JavaScript strings by mashing PHP strings together. Use a robust escaping function. `json_encode` will give you the JavaScript literal (including quote characters where needed) for any simple data structure.
- Do not try to generate HTML by mashing strings together. Use a robust escaping function. `htmlspecialchars` will do all you need.

Such:

```
onClick="window.open(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($a)); ?>)"
```

---

But don't use JavaScript when HTML will do:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($a); ?>" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo "'$a'"`. The main problem is that you would habe double-double quotes in your onclick attribute. Or even better `window.open('<?php echo $a; ?>')`.